# Better method for solving ODE $yy''+ (y')^2-(y')^3\ln (y)=0$

Tags: real-analysis, calculus, ordinary-differential-equations, derivatives

What's a better way to solve this equation?

$$yy''+ (y')^2-(y')^3\ln (y)=0 $$

so far, I've tried:

- reducing the order of the equation ($p=y'$):  $yp'+ p^2-p^3ln(y)=0 $
- dividing everything by $p^3$: $y\frac{p'}{p^3} + \frac{1}{p}=ln(y)$
- solving the homogeneous equation: $y\frac{p'}{p^3} + \frac{1}{p}=0 \implies p=(\frac{1}{3ln(cy)})^\frac{1}{3}$

but using constant variation to solve this from this point on seems unnecessarily complicated. Is there a better method I'm not seeing?

Comment: Hint: $y y'' + y'^2 = \frac{d}{dx} (y y') $

Answer (score 3, accepted):

As I stated in the comments, use the fact that

$$y y'' + y'^2 = \frac{d}{dx} (y y')$$

Then

$$\frac{d}{dx} (y y') = y'^3 \log{y} $$

This may be rewritten as

$$\frac{d(y y')}{(y y')^2} = \frac{\log{y}}{y^2} y' dx = \frac{\log{y}}{y^2} dy$$

This equation may be integrated to produce

$$-\frac1{y y'} + C_1 = -\frac{1+\log{y}}{y} $$

Rearrange to get

$$y' = \frac1{1+\log{y}-C_1 y}$$

which may be expressed as

$$(1+\log{y}-C_1 y) dy = dx$$

which may be integrated again to produce

> $$x = y \log{y} - \frac12 C_1 y^2 + C_2$$

which is about as far as I can take this.

Answer (score 1):

$$yy''+ (y')^2-(y´)^3\ln (y)=0$$
Consider $x'$

And note that

$$y''=\frac 1{x'}\frac {d}{dy} \frac 1 {x'}=-\frac {x''}{x'^3}$$
$$yy''+ (y')^2-(y´)^3\ln (y)=0$$
The differential equation becomes:
$$-x''y+ x'=\ln |y|$$
Substitute  $z=x'$ it's a first order linear equation:
$$z'y-z=-\ln |y|$$
Or multiply by $y$
$$y^2x''- yx'=-y\ln |y|$$
Then it's Cauchy-Euler's equation.